# Close Google From Responses for time pereiod

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I am wanting my google form to not allow any responses between 1:45 pm and 2:45 pm every day and open back up after that time frame and repeat this process every day.  I've tried a couple of add-ons that do not like the open time after the close time so I'm looking for a script, trigger, anything that will do this for me.  And a bonus of being able to show a message that it is closed would be a great bonus but not necessary.

Comment: What is the purpose?

Comment: [setAcceptingResponses(enabled)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#setAcceptingResponses(Boolean))

Comment: I have the form recording responses that need to be finalized at a specific time each day so that entries are not missed.  So I need it to block off that period of time so that there are no entries missed.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a new [standalone Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/standalone) project and add the code below:

```
function openForm() {
  FormApp.openById('your-form-id').setAcceptingResponses(true);
}

function closeForm() {
  FormApp.openById('your-form-id').setAcceptingResponses(false);  
}
```

Then, create [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) in this project to run these functions in specific times. You must keep in mind, as said in documentation:

> The time may be slightly randomized — for example, if you create a recurring 9 a.m. trigger, Apps Script chooses a time between 9 a.m. and 10 a.m., then keeps that timing consistent from day to day so that 24 hours elapse before the trigger fires again.

Comment: You can fetch form id in the link: `https://docs.google.com/forms/d/{form-id-comes-here}/edit`